# Importing videos in Mathematica

Tags: import, video

Mathematica's `Import` command is purportedly able to import .AVI files. However, I find that many files that I want to import do only result in MMA showing a blank frame or another placeholder. All or some of my video-players are able to show these AVI files.

This is an example where it works as advertised:

```
Import["http://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/jfkrice.avi", {"ImageList", 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However,

```
Import["http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/avi/ccvt_box.avi", {"ImageList", 2}]
```

doesn't work (VLC does). I get an empty white frame.

More examples:

```
Import["http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/avi/sine_wave.avi", {"ImageList", 2}]
```

(works on VLC and mediaplayer classic)

```
Import["http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/avi/star_collapse.avi", {"ImageList", 2}]
```

**BIG-126 MB!!**
Should have looked  like this:
[image: Mathematica graphics]
 and works on Windows Media Player, VLC and mediaplayer classic, but I get a white box in MMA.

This is on windows 7-64/MMA8.04. I have the k-lite codecs pack installed.

---

**UPDATE**

Responding to Thomas' comment below I found most of the sample files I linked to in my original post gone. I tried to gather a new set and found some that worked and some that don't:

Importable:

```
Import[#, "VideoEncoding"] & /@ 
 {"http://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/jfkrice.avi", 
  "http://redmine.yorba.org/attachments/615/MVI_0572.AVI",
  "http://www-eng-x.llnl.gov/documents/a_video.avi",
  "http://redmine.yorba.org/attachments/628/MVI_4981.AVI",
  "http://www.csoft.co.uk/video/original/earth.avi",
  "http://www.mysticfractal.com/video/fp.avi", 
  "http://www.softage.ru/files/video-codec/uncompressed/suzie.avi", 
  "http://archive.org/download/Architects_of_Tomorrow/2007-12-10-02-39-00.avi"}
```

> {"msvc", "MJPG", "msvc", "MJPG", "msvc", "msvc", "YUV", "Uncompressed"}

Don't import:

```
Import[#, "VideoEncoding"] & /@
 {"https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/export/7213/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/HighGUI/video-input-psnr-ssim/video/Megamind.avi",
  "http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/avi/verona60avi56k.avi",
  "http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/avi/filedoesitbetter.avi",
  "http://www.infognition.com/ScreenPressor/browsing-divx.avi"
  }
```

> {"XVID", "MP42", "MJPG", "DX50"}

Comment: I think it has to do with how it is encoded. A lot of the video files you see floating on the internet with a `.avi` extension are _not really_ AVI files. I'm don't think that mma utilizes the codecs in your system, whereas VLC does. As such, mma can only import videos that are truthful to the AVI specs (if there are any)

Comment: @R.M The problem is that AVI is a container which may hold variously encoded material. Apparently, but not entirely understandable, MMA is not able to handle many codecs although they are present on my PC. However, I would have expected the Microsoft test movies to work, as they are explicitly meant as confirming to MS standards.

Comment: <insert _"MS has standards?"_ joke here?> :)

Comment: I am not that familiar with Windows's multimedia playback system, but my guess is this: Windows has two big frameworks: Video for Windows (VfW) and DirectShow (DS).  VfW is outdated, but seems to be still used by Mathematica.  When you install codecs, most of them are made for DS, and won't work with VfW.

Comment: This may be a Windows-specific issue: With Mathematica 8.0.4 under Mac OS X 10.6.8, I evaluated each of the Import commands you listed, and every one of them worked except for the final one -- the star collapse. But even for that one, I don't get a white box; rather, I get a black box with some variegated pixels in a band along the top of that box. I cannot test the Microsoft .avi's you cite, since the link you gave is to an .exe, and of course an .exe is not an OS X executable.

Comment: I cannot directly test the Microsoft .avi's you cite, since the link you gave is to an .exe, and of course an .exe is not an OS X executable. However, I did download and run that .exe under Windows 7 inside a Parallels Desktop virtual machine. When I do, nothing seems to happen. What should happen when one executes it?

Comment: @murray It is supposed to expand into two video files.  When I launched it from firefox nothing seemed to happen. After visiting it in the file browser and executing I found the two files residing in the same folder. For now I've copied them to here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675222/SAMPLE.AVI and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675222/WNDSURF1.AVI

Comment: @murray Of course you're right, that .exe files are not properly Mac OS X executables. But I've seen many a .exe file in Activity Monitor or 'top' - 'PNG.exe' or 'XML.exe', for example. These are named by our good friends at Wolfram Research... :)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Your dropbox-ed AVI files import correctly on Mac OS X running 10.7. It seems that Mathematica relies on the OS for video importing capabilities, so perhaps this is more of a Windows-related question. Having said that, like many Mac users, I've installed Perian as a matter of routine, which probably helps with non-Apple video formats.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries As a workaround you could use something like ffmpeg to save the individual frames as a list of .jpegs and import those into Mathematica.

Comment: @heike I have been using VirtualDub for that goal (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5640317/615464), but still this and your workaround are a kludge. I really would like mathematica to use the codecs as other applications are able to.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Are there any updates on this with current versions of Mathematica? I am currently running into the same problem: white frame when importing (codec of the avi file: DX50)

Comment: @thomas See update above, tried with version 9, but also: do read Arnoud Buzing's answer below. It doesn't seem to depend on Mathematica but on Quicktime.

Comment: Thank you for the generous bounty!

Comment: @SimonWoods It's almost there. Just holding it to draw a few more spectators to your answer ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**64-bit Windows only**

> Note for *Mathematica* 11.3: There is a potential conflict between `MathMF` and the built-in `MediaTools` package. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186349/862) for details and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186990/862) for an example of how to use `MediaTools` in place of `MathMF`.

> Note for *Mathematica* version 10: The Wolfram Library has been updated in version 10 and you will need to recompile the MathMF DLL. This is most easily accomplished by evaluating `"MathMF"//FindLibrary//DeleteFile` prior to loading the package.

[Link to package on GitHub](https://github.com/SimonWoods/MathMF/)

I have written a package called *MathMF* which uses a `LibraryLink` DLL to do frame-by-frame video import and export with Windows Media Foundation. It should be able to read a reasonable variety of movie files, including AVI, WMV and MP4. Exporting is currently limited to WMV and MP4 formats (AVI encoding is not natively supported by Media Foundation)

Here is the sort of code you can write with it. The code first opens a video file for reading, and creates a new video file for writing to. It then runs a loop in which each frame is sequentially read from the input stream, processed in *Mathematica* and then written to the output stream. So *Mathematica* is effectively being used as a video filter.

```
{duration, framerate, width, height} =
 MFInitSourceReader["C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\test1.wmv"];

MFInitSinkWriter["C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\filtered.wmv", 
 width, height, "FrameRate" -> framerate]

While[
  (image = MFGrabFrame["RealImage"]) =!= EndOfFile,
  MFSendFrame @ GradientFilter[image, 2]
  ] ~Monitor~ image

MFFinaliseSink[]
```

The package can be downloaded from the GitHub link at the top of this post, it is too large to include in full here.

The package includes the library source code, and on first use will attempt to compile the library locally. I believe the compilation should work if you have Visual Studio 2010 or later installed, and probably won't work if you use a different compiler. There is a pre-built DLL available if the compilation fails (see the readme on GitHub for more details)

I hope some people find this useful, it has been hovering in my mind as something to try to do for quite some time, hindered mainly by my total lack of experience with C++ and COM programming.

Comment: Excellent Simon! I had to download the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 before it worked for me, but after that, flawless. One small point: I don't think we should distribute software in the form of binaries, as that can have terrible security implications.

Comment: @Sjoerd, thank you. I agree about distributing the binary, I have now uploaded a .m package and the C++ source code. The package will attempt to build the library from source when it is first loaded. There are various header files which the compiler needs, I **think** any system with VS2012 or the Win7 SDK will have these available but I'm not sure. I'd be grateful if you could try it out when you have the chance.

Comment: as confirmed in chat, compiling works. Using avi to wmv converters available on the internet should allow avi import as well.

Comment: @Sjoerd, avi import should just work. MF supports reading avi, just not writing.

Comment: @Simon Woods: Please have a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186349/question-regarding-mathmf. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

(Thanks to K.H. from Wolfram):

Even on Windows, if QuickTime is installed, Mathematica uses the native QuickTime 
install (excluding added, third-party codecs) to import AVI files, and the supported 
codecs are listed in:

```
Internal`$VideoEncodings
```

(Without an installation of QuickTime, only uncompressed AVI files are supported by Mathematica.)  For the file http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/avi/ccvt_box.avi, QuickTime on Windows can not open it, so Mathematica has problem importing it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. So, we must hope Apple upgrades QT a bit then...

Comment: Given the current legal wranglings over video formats, and the fact that AVI is considered to be inferior to current formats, and the fact that Apple doesn't like supporting other people's technology, hope is the operative word...

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to access the video frame by frame you can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to decode the video.

Reposting a  [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19025/1517):

---

If you only want to read it linearly you can tell ffmpeg to dump the video to stdout and then read width*height*bytes-per-pixel bytes at a time to get the video frame-by-frame:

```
openVideo[fname_, w_, h_] := 
 Module[{video}, 
  video["stream"] = 
   OpenRead[
    "!ffmpeg -i " ~~ fname ~~ " -loglevel quiet -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -", 
    BinaryFormat -> True];
  video["SkipFrame", n_Integer: 1] := Skip[video["stream"], Byte, n*3*w*h];
  video["NextFrame"] := Partition[Partition[
     BinaryReadList[video["stream"], "Byte", 3*w*h]
   , 3], w];
  video["NextFrame", n_Integer] := Table[video["NextFrame"], {n}];
  video["NextImage"] := Image[video["NextFrame"], "Byte"];
  video["NextImage", n_Integer] := Table[video["NextImage"], {n}];
  video]
```

Here's an example:

```
(* Create a test movie *)
file = $TemporaryPrefix <> "testvid.avi";
Export[file,Table[Rasterize[i, ImageSize -> {352, 200}], {i, 1, 50}]];

video = openVideo[file,352,200]
video["NextImage",2]
video["SkipFrame",10]
video["NextImage"]
```

[image: first]

[image: second]

For some reason Mathematica seems to read through the entire video when doing `Close[video["stream"]]` and it might be worth to `kill -15` the ffmpeg process manually to speed it up for large files.

For a 720x404 h264 mp4 video on a modest laptop it takes 13s to skip 200 frames and 0.07s to read a frame. The skipping could possibly be sped up by starting a new ffmpeg process that begins at desired frame. I would compare speeds to `Import` but Mathematica can't read it (for the test video Import takes .2s for first frame compared to .02s ). So as a bonus with this way you can work with many many more video formats :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I tested that ffmpeg is present; tried it either with specifying its full path, and without path but directory set with `SetDirectory`. Nothing. Also tested with `ReadList["!\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ConvertHelper\\ffmpeg.exe\" -h \
", String]` that ffmpeg actually executes. It does.

Comment: There is a minus sign without option letter at the end of the ffmpeg call.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The last - makes it output to stdout, do you get anything interesting on stderr when running from a terminal without `-loglevel quiet`? (Whatever windows equivalent of `ffmpeg -i video.avi  -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 - >/dev/null` is, maybe `> nul`)

Comment: For comparison, this is what I get for above test video: http://pastie.org/7458920

Comment: I upgraded ffmpeg to a newer version. That did the trick. Thanks!  An improvement would be to remove the need to enter the frame size.

Comment: With Mathematica 10 on OS X 10.9.1, I get errors: `video = openVideo[file,352,200]` -> `"video$843"`; `video["NextImage", 2]` -> `"Image::imgarray: The specified argument {} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>"` `"{Image[{}, "Byte"], Image[{}, "Byte"]}"`

Comment: A Library for importing using FFmpeg: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47545/4568

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the fact that you cannot open the video at

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/avi/ccvt_box.avi

by QuickTime. Try it. Download free QuickTime and try to open it in that player and is most probably won't work. It means that to make the video a non-standard video encoding was used  which is not a subset of formats understood by QuickTime. High chance this is why M. cannot open it - my best guess.

Comment: Well, I'm on windows and Quicktime player is not the first choice on that platform. Anyway, that doesn't show a thing. As I wrote above, all the movies listed can be played by one of  more of the players I have on my PC. The codec pack installed on my PC makes an enormous amount of standard and exotic codecs available to Windows and any player/importer that uses the appropriate system API should be able to use them. It looks like MMA doesn't go through the codecs that are installed on the machine and instead only uses a few built-in codecs; apparently a very small set.