# How to efficiently import videos

Tags: import, video

I need to do frame-by-frame analysis of videos. I can import the video files I need, but each file is too large to import at once. I can use the `Import[fn, "Frames",{n}]` command to import images one-by-one, but this takes a long time once `n` gets large. For example, the first frame it takes 0.14 sec, but the 200th frame takes 2.2 sec. Mathematica seems to be reading from the start of the file each time I do this. Obviously, this will not work.
  Is there some way to speed this up. E.g. using streams? Or tricking Mathematica to use `ImageCapture` to get images from a video file instead of a webcam?
Thanks

Comment: You can use ffmpeg or similar to export each frame as an image named like *frame-%d.png* and then you can easily import one chunk of frames at a time by reading appropriate file.

Comment: [Streams](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamMethods.html) does have a certain appeal. It is to bad I don't have time to put something together for it.

Comment: What format is your video file? I tried a quick test with an AVI file and found that all frames took about the same amount of time to import.

Comment: You can also import a list of frames: `Import[movie,   {"ImageList", Range[...]}]`

Answer (score 15):

### About:

This is my second answer. After playing with *Mathematica*'s video import I have noticed that it makes import mistakes (duplicated frames + artifacts) and thus developed `ffmpeg` package for *Mathematica* which is based on [ssch answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19025/1356).

https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica

The speed of this package is as follows on moderate computer:

- Importing **one frame** is from **2 to 100 times slower**, because current method for seeking frame is slow.
- Importing **many frames (1000+)** is from **2 to 10 times faster**.

I am switching to `ffmpeg` importer because for bulk analysis it proved to be faster and more accurate than default method.

### Usage:

Mimicking *Mathematica*'s `Import` function:

```
FFImport[ "file.avi", {"Frames", 1}]
```

gives first frame (slow way).

```
FFImport[ "file.avi", {"Frames", Range[1,1000]}]
```

gives first 1000 frames (fast)

To test status of `ffmpeg` library you can run `FFmpeg[]`.

More information about `ffmpeg` installation in the [link above](https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica).

Comment: @Öskå, I just updated the package for RGB support.

Comment: Works like a charm now indeed, and it's much faster +1

Comment: BTW, seeking is still very slow using ffmpeg - do you have an idea how to speed it up?

Comment: When I try to import video file using FFImport, I am getting errors BinaryReadList::strmerr: Error on stream !/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "30.796.avi" -frames:v 30163 -loglevel quiet -f rawvideo  -pix_fmt  rgb24 -. Error message: ø½\[CapitalZeta] >>

General::stop: Further output of BinaryReadList::strmerr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>  and it truncates mathematica. Can you help me.

Comment: Have you installed ffmpeg via Homebrew?see description in GitHub.

Comment: Hi, yes I did. brew install ffmpeg
Warning: ffmpeg-2.3.1 already installed

Comment: I added some updates to the program. Does it work for you now?

Comment: I tested your software with the following video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfNENvNHJMRGc0SG8 . It produces only black Images. Where is the error?

Comment: Submit an issue at https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica/issues . Stack overflow comments are a wrong place

Comment: @mrz, I think it is a problem with the command for ffmpeg. It must be related to the particular format you are using. I recommend playing with the commands to see what helps and modifying it in the source code.

Answer (score 14):

If you only want to read it linearly you can tell ffmpeg to dump the video to stdout and then read width*height*bytes-per-pixel bytes at a time to get the video frame-by-frame:

```
openVideo[fname_, w_, h_] := 
 Module[{video}, 
  video["stream"] = 
   OpenRead[
    "!ffmpeg -i " ~~ fname ~~ " -loglevel quiet -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -", 
    BinaryFormat -> True];
  video["SkipFrame", n_Integer: 1] := Skip[video["stream"], Byte, n*3*w*h];
  video["NextFrame"] := Partition[Partition[
     BinaryReadList[video["stream"], "Byte", 3*w*h]
   , 3], w];
  video["NextFrame", n_Integer] := Table[video["NextFrame"], {n}];
  video["NextImage"] := Image[video["NextFrame"], "Byte"];
  video["NextImage", n_Integer] := Table[video["NextImage"], {n}];
  video]
```

Here's an example:

```
(* Create a test movie *)
file = $TemporaryPrefix <> "testvid.avi";
Export[file,Table[Rasterize[i, ImageSize -> {352, 200}], {i, 1, 50}]];

video = openVideo[file,352,200]
video["NextImage",2]
video["SkipFrame",10]
video["NextImage"]
```

[image: first]

[image: second]

For some reason Mathematica seems to read through the entire video when doing `Close[video["stream"]]` and it might be worth to `kill -15` the ffmpeg process manually to speed it up for large files.

For a 720x404 h264 mp4 video on a modest laptop it takes 13s to skip 200 frames and 0.07s to read a frame. The skipping could possibly be sped up by starting a new ffmpeg process that begins at desired frame. I would compare speeds to `Import` but Mathematica can't read it (for the test video Import takes .2s for first frame compared to .02s ). So as a bonus with this way you can work with many many more video formats :)

Comment: This works for me very well. However, I would like to add that it is absolutely necessary that the file name doesn't contain any spaces.

Answer (score 12):

The performance can be improved by loading more than 100 frames at a time. To test this we can run:

```
LoadNFrames[n_] := (Import[video , {"Frames" , Range[1000, 1000 + n]} ]; n);

times = Table[ AbsoluteTiming[ LoadNFrames[n] ], 
         {n, {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800}}]
```

[image: time it takes to load a frame VS frames loaded]

One can see that in Mathematica there is a penalty for loading only few frames. We can improve the performance by preloading the video and storing it in a buffer. For instance:

```
buffer = Import[video, "ImageList"]; 

GetFrame[n_] := buffer[[n]]
```

The method uses a lot of memory, therefore, for large videos you will need to load  parts of the video. I also typically cut the region of interest before putting it o the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

If using Windows you can try my MathMF package (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/862)) which loads video frames sequentially using the Media Foundation platform via LibraryLink.

The speed is pretty good. Exact timings will vary according to CPU speed and the performance of the decoder, but as an example my PC here can read a 1280x720 WMV file at 25 frames per second and a 760x554 AVI file at 73 frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform a frame by frame operation, you could use something like VideoMapList:

```
VideoMapList[myOperation[#Image]&, video]
```

This will apply `myOperation` to each frame, and return all the results in a list. The time to fetch the frames this way is much faster than the  Import strategy.

Another advantage is that only one frame will be in memory at any one time.