# Extract frames as image files from video files

Tags: programming, video

I have a set of video files where the frame rate is 1 frame/sec and the file shows the evolution of a particular object with time. Now, I want to extract each frame of the video and analyze as seperate images. Is it possible to use mathematica to do it? I know that it is possible to use mathematica to connect a set of images to convert into video but is the reverse possible?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18335/how-to-efficiently-import-videos) help?

Comment: Thanks for the reply march. I think that above link is to import the files and create a video file. For the current problem, I want to do the opposite thing, i.e., to extract the images from the video filed. I have been able to do it using a third party software (a well known media player) but using that software it takes time to extract the frames.

Comment: Really? I read that post as talking about importing a video file as a sequence of frames. I don't have experience with frame capture in Mathematica, so I did a search within Mathematica.SE for related posts, and that one seemed promising. I guess we'll have to wait for others with more experience to answer the question.

Comment: Matcax I would suggest that you re-read the post that @march suggested. It really seems to refer to the same import process that you are interested in, and not in generating new video files.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the older [Importing videos in MMA](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/importing-videos-in-mathematica).