# Video encodings in Ubuntu

Tags: export, video

When exporting videos from Mathematica 10.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04, I have **one** video codec to choose from:

```
Internal`$VideoEncodings
(* {"Uncompressed"} *)
```

That means exporting 100 frames of a 512x512px grayscale video as an AVI results in an 80 Mb file.

Now, I can subsequently convert the video with [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and get it down to much, much smaller file sizes. 
However, is there a way to access more video codecs directly from Mathematica on Ubuntu? I've followed advice such as [How to install all existing media codecs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171026/how-to-install-all-existing-media-codecs) to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the answer here from Arnoud Buzing: [Importing videos in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/394/13162)

> Even on Windows, if QuickTime is installed, Mathematica uses the native QuickTime install (excluding added, third-party codecs) to import AVI files...Without an installation of QuickTime, only uncompressed AVI files are supported by Mathematica

Which suggests the answer may well be no on Ubuntu. FFmpeg it is!