# Stitching Mathematica-produced movies together

Tags: export, animation

I have hundred thousands of images from a numerical simulation and want to make a movie from them. This is easy done with

```
Export["movie.mov", imagelist]
```

However, if `imagelist` consists of hundred thousands of images, my computer simply needs ages or shuts down. I thought, to solve this problem, I make smaller movies, each consisting of e.g. 10.000 images. This runs comparatively fast. Then I end up with x numbers of short movies. Now I would like to stitch them together into one single movie. Is there a way to do this with *Mathematica*? If so, it would be great as I could then constantly add new frames from my running simulation (which takes days) to my movie.

Comment: I would recommend a *non*-Mathematica based solution like ffmpeg.

Comment: Sure, I can use iMovie, but it would be nice to keep it all under the hood of a single software.

Comment: I believe that any MMA-based solution would require importing the pieces of the movie all at once, then exporting them together: which is exactly what you say is giving you problems.  [FFMPEG will easily concatenate video files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) from the command line, so you should be able to use it via a system call from MMA if you so desire.

Comment: OK, I probably don't know how this works. If it should not be possible with MMA, I probably use iMovie.

Comment: If you have more than a few files, using iMovie will be a PITA.  Once I get home to my linux box I'll whip up an example that should be mostly portable to OS X.  In the meantime you can [download the binaries](http://ffmpegmac.net/) for your version of OS X and unpack them into the directory where your movies are.

Comment: One other thing: the images take up GB, but the final .mov file only maybe a few tens of MB. So importing and stitching the videos – if possible – might not be so memory critical. – Also, I use iMovie a lot, and so far it's working fine.

Comment: MMA represents videos as lists of (uncompressed) frames, so the file will balloon out to tens of GB in memory when `Import`ed.

Comment: this is what I do -- cannot recall where I got it from -- `cat part1.avi part2.avi part3.avi > tmp.avi && mencoder -forceidx -oac copy -ovc copy tmp.avi -o output.avi && rm -f tmp.avi`

Answer (score 10):

The way I typically handle this type of situation is to export the individual images, then have software like FFmpeg handle the conversion to video.  FFmpeg in particular is an extremely powerful tool (and is available for Windows, OS X, and most Linux distros).

---

First [download the appropriate binary](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) for your system. I placed the `ffmpeg` binary in the folder `se-temp`.  Let's find it:

```
tempDir = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "se-temp"}];
SetDirectory[tempDir];
FileNames[]

(* {"ffmpeg.exe"} *)
```

Yeah, I'm doing this from Windows.  Don't worry though, the only change you should have to make if you're on Linux or OS X is to remove the `.exe` from the command name.  In fact, let me do that for you:

```
command = First@FileNames["ffmpeg*"];
```

We can use the (new in v10) function `RunProcess` to check that we can call FFmpeg from Mathematica.

```
RunProcess[{command, "-version"}, "StandardOutput"]

(*
  ffmpeg version N-72086-g51f6455 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads ...
*)
```

If you're on an earlier version, you can use `Run` instead:

```
Run[command, "-version"]
(* 0 *)
```

`0` tells us that the command was executed successfully (errors typically result in nonzero exit codes).  If you're on Windows, a terminal window will flash open while the command is running.

Now let's generate some images:

```
r = 24;
l = 12;
imgs = Join @@ 
   Table[Graphics[{If[
       10 >= n > 2 && 
        f > 0, {{EdgeForm[
          Directive[Black, Thickness[1/200], JoinForm["Round"]]], 
         GrayLevel[0.5], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, 19, Pi/2 - {0, 2 Pi f/r}]}, {Black, 
         Thickness[1/500], 
         Line[{{{-16, 0}, {+16, 0}}, {{0, -9}, {0, 9}}}]}, {White, 
         Thickness[1/120], Circle[{0, 0}, 7], 
         Circle[{0, 0}, 8]}}], {Black, 
       Text[Style[n, 400], {0, 0}, {0, 0}]}}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-16, 16}, {-9, 9}}, 
     Background -> 
      If[10 >= n > 2 || (f == 0 && n >= 2), GrayLevel[0.8], Black], 
     ImageSize -> 1280], {n, Reverse@Range[l]}, {f, Range[r] - 1}];
```

`r` sets the framerate, and `l` sets the number of seconds.  Just for fun, we can also generate some sound:

```
fs = 48000;
sound = Flatten[
   N@Table[Boole[n == 2 && f == 0] Sin[2 Pi*1000 s/fs], {n, 
      Reverse@Range[l]}, {f, Range[r] - 1}, {s, fs/r}]];
```

(Ok, it's not an aural masterpiece: less Tupac and more [2-pop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-pop).)  The parameters are the same as before, except now we have the sampling rate `fs`.

Let's export:

```
imgName[i_Integer] := imgName @ IntegerString[i, 10, 4]
imgName[s_String]  := "img" <> s <> ".png"
soundName = "audio.wav";
MapIndexed[Export[imgName[First@#2], #1] &, imgs];
Export[soundName, ListPlay[sound, SampleRate -> fs]];
```

Finally we can call `ffmpeg` to join our images into a video:

```
RunProcess[{command, "-y", "-r", ToString@r, "-f", "image2", "-i", imgName["%04d"], "-i", soundName, vidName}];
```

Or using `Run`:

```
Run[command, "-y", "-r", r, "-f", "image2", "-i", imgName["%04d"], "-i", soundName, vidName];
```

This runs the following command:

```bash
ffmpeg
 -y                # overwrite output if already exists
 -r 24             # declares input frame rate
 -f image2         # declares input format
 -i "img%04d.png"  # input image name
 -i audio.wav      # input audio name
 video.mp4         # output name
```

Finally, we should clean up after ourselves by deleting the image files:

```
DeleteFile @* imgName /@ Range[Length[imgs]];
```

---

If you have a bunch of already-existing video files that you want to concatenate, FFmpeg will [do that too](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

First we need to create a temporary file with the list of videos to concatenate:

```
listName = "list.txt";
videos = {"video.mp4", "video.mp4"};
Export[listName, 
  StringJoin[
   Riffle["file \"" <> # <> "\"" & /@ 
     StringReplace[videos, {"\"" -> "\\\"", "\\" -> "\\\\"}], "\n"]]];
```

Then we run the command:

```
vidName = "videoDoubled.mp4";
RunProcess[{command, "-y", "-f", "concat", "-i", listName, "-c", "copy", vidName}];
```

Since our list had `"video.mp4"` twice, the new video is just the old video repeated twice; but you get the idea.

Finally we clean up:

```
DeleteFile /@ videos;
DeleteFile @ listName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows users can use my [MathMF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/862) package for this. There's no need to export the frames as images, you just write them directly to a video stream as you create them. It doesn't have the flexibility of third party tools like ffmpeg but it's good for a quick and easy video export without storing all frames in memory. Example code:

```
Needs["MathMF`"]

{w, h} = {300, 200};
frame[i_] := Rasterize[i, "Data", ImageSize -> {w, h}]

MFInitSinkWriter["C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\example.wmv", w, h, "FrameRate" -> 25]

Do[MFSendFrame @ frame[i], {i, 1, 100}]

MFFinaliseSink[]
```

Comment: +1 I take this opportunity to tell you that your package works great for me. I've been importing a lot of videos, with zero problems! THANK YOU