# How to sample n frames from a movie file?

Tags: import

I'm looking to import 100 image frames from an mp4 video file at roughly evenly spaced intervals. As $ImportFormats shows, Mathematica can handle

- **Movie files:** .avi, .mov, .qt, .flv
- **Multiframe images:** .swf, .tiff, .gif

If I convert the video it to a supported type, what would the syntax be to achieve this import, I don't want to import all the frames and then take a few!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Import` directly as follows:

```
Import["MVI_9855-183.mp4", {"AVI", "ImageList", Range[1, 110, 20]}]
```

This will import one frame every 20, between the first and 100th, and return them as a list of pictures.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see above, at least in the case of the mp4 files I have at hand I was able to "convince" *Mathematica* to import them directly by specifying the AVI format for the file. I am no expert in video file format, however, so I can't claim that I understand why that worked, or whether it will work for you as well.

---

If you are on Windows, you may also be interested in Simon Woods's *MathMF* package that carried out video input output functions using Windows Media Foundation. See it described in his answer to this question: [Importing videos in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/27951)

Comment: Weird! Nice trick though, do you know how to get the total frame count?

Comment: Oh it's just "FrameCount"

Comment: And the "AVI" is not necessary.

Comment: @M.R. so it works without the "AVI" on your side even if the file extension is *not* \*.avi? That's interesting: if I try to feed an *.mp4 file directly to Import it fails, saying "Cannot import data as ImageList".