# Importing .AVI to mathematica and frame extraction

Tags: import, video, format

I'm trying to import frames from a video with the extension [.avi](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/AVI.html), using this piece of *Mathematica* code:

```
Import["video.AVI", {"Frames", {5, 6}}]
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot import data as videoformat.

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried: 

Import["video.AVI"]
Import["video.AVI" ,"AVI"]

What messages do you get?

Comment: @Searke Yes I did and I get an array of indices indicating each frame.

Comment: And the examples for AVI importing in the documentation work for you?

Comment: @Searke No, it does not. That I don't get. The importing of frames doesn't work.

Comment: In the documentation, It´s importing frames as a .avi file and then having them imported back.

Comment: I'm not sure I have a good idea of how to debug this then. If none of the documentation examples work and you can't export an AVI file and then import it back... What OS are you using and what version of Mathematica?

Comment: @Searke OS Windows 7 Enterprise 32 bit - Mathematica 10.4

Comment: I would contact wolfram technical support (probably by email) if no one comes up with a suggestion.

Comment: In the documentation example is it exporting the movie okay, but failing to import it?

Comment: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/385261?p_p_auth=5mj3jDt1 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/importing-videos-in-mathematica may or may not be helpful.

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks.

Comment: faf, If you are willing to go through the extra effort to install ffmpeg, then [this package](https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica) looks perfectly suited to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I checked it with 64-bit OS and it worked. Apparently It only work in 64-bit version of windows (7).