# QuickTime install not recognized

Tags: windows, installation, video

I am using Mathematica 10.4.1 Free Trial on Windows 10 and I have QuickTime Player 7.7.9 installed but I still get `QuickTime format is supported only if QuickTime Player is installed.` When I try to import an MOV file.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/394/39584) is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't a problem with my install, I just had to restart my computer. Maybe it had to update the Windows Registry.