# MP4 won't import

Tags: import, video

I am having trouble importing the  8MB mp4 file available at [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNEyJIIE0e8WDRKOVREejJqWVU) link. It was recorded on my Digital Camera and is 1920x1080 30fps.

I've tried `vid = Import["C:\\Users\\Patrick\\MyRocketVideo.mp4", "AVI"]`, but all it returns is `$Failed`!

I'm using `"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"`

Can anyone confirm this? Or find a way around this.

Comment: Its working fine on `11.0`

Comment: It works on OS X too, with M 11.0.1. But I am surprised that it works.  AVI and MP4 are two different container formats.  This is not an AVI file.  Why should it work when you try to import it as such?  One *guess* is that Mathematica simply asks the operating system to interpret the file, and Mathematica itself doesn't really care about either the container format or the codec used. This would explain why I can import it as "AVI", even though it isn't one. It could be that your computer doesn't have the necessary codecs to deal with MP4 (at least not within the framework that Mathematica...

Comment: ... tries to use to interpret the file). This would explain why it works for @MapleSE but not for you (assuming he also uses Windows).  I don't use Windows anymore so I don't know what is the current best way to install codecs. You may want to try a codec pack like http://www.cccp-project.net/ but be aware that some of these can also break stuff (not only fix stuff). I used to use this one years ago.

Comment: Otherwise, you can use ffmpeg or ImageMagick to convert the video to a sequence of images, then import the images one by one. You will need to install these tools and read up on how to use them from the command line. I can never remember the correct syntax, so I cannot tell you right now.  But it shouldn't take long to look it up.

Comment: I am using `11.0` on Windows `10`.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/importing-videos-in-mathematica)?