# How to extract all images from avi when FrameRate is not Integer

Tags: export, image-processing, png-format

Here is an avi movie (204*432 Pixels) which contains **22 different images** with numbers from 1 to 22. I tested e.g. with VirtualDub and MATLAB that all extracted images are different.

Movie: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfUE1hb0UyNXhDRFk

(5.5MB)

**When I extract the images with the mathematica code below image 20 is same as image 19.** All the rest is correct.

The two same images are seen here:

```
Import[avifile, {"AVI", "ImageList", Range[19, 20, 1]}]
```

[image]

> The error occurs due to the non integer `FrameRate`:
>
> ```
> Import[avifile, {"FrameRate"}]
>
> 15.7143
> ```

VirtualDub and other software do not care about the frame rate. They simply extract sequentially image by image and the result is corrrect:

```
{Import["virtualdub_000019.png"], Import["virtualdub_000020.png"]}
```

[image]

**Do you know a solution for mathematica?**

My code for extracting grayscale images is:

```
avifile = "20170623_movie_for_testing_duplicate_images.avi";

numberImages = Length@Import[avifile, "Frames"]

22

Do[

  image = ColorConvert[Import[avifile, {"Frames", i}], "Grayscale"];

  fileNameCounter = ToString@PaddedForm[i, 6, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}];

  Export[StringJoin[fileNameCounter, ".png"], image];

  , {i, 1, numberImages}

  ];
```

For comparison here are all extracted

- mathematica images: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfVFRtRm4tTjhMVTQ
- VirtualDub images: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfc2s0a1BGR3l1NjA

Comment: I tried extracting the frames with ffmpeg as well, and that also shows that image 19 and 20 are not the same. Despite what *Mathematica* thinks.

Comment: But why is mathematica doing something different with frame 20? All other images are the same as extracted with VirtualDub and probably also with ffmpeg.

Comment: I would report it as a bug.

Comment: @C. E. The error with mathematica occurs due to the non integer `FrameRate`.

Comment: ok, nice that you figured it out.

Comment: can you import all, `Import[avifile,"ImageList"]` and extract the frames you want with `Part` ?  (That will likely be faster anyway unless the file is too big to load in memory all at once )

Comment: @george2079: Unfortunately this does not help. See: http://imgur.com/gallery/mQyAM

Comment: This is NOT the case with Mathematica 9.0.1.0 (Win7 64-bit). In 9.0.1, I get the correct sequence of images from 1 to 22 with `Import[..., "ImageList"]`.

Comment: Not with 11.0.1.0 either... I cannot confirm what you have observed. I do not know how Mathematica handles the import of video files. Can it be a codec issue?

Comment: I get the expected output with *Mathematica* 11.1.1, 11.0.1, 10.4.1 and 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64. Which OS/ *Mathematica* version do you use?

Comment: Thank you to everybody. I am using Window 10 Pro (64Bit), Mathematica 11.1.1. Could you please show me exactly the code you used for the test, so that I can check it? If I don't succeed, would it be possible to chat with you? I have also a Mac and will make the test there (will let you know).

Comment: Test with my mac (macOS Sierra, 10.12.5, Mathematica 11.1.1): still the same problem. I downloaded the video from link (in the question) and used the code shown here: http://imgur.com/8nvUeZq. *What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: I get the correct output with Mathematica 11.1.1 on Windows 10 (64 bit). I used the exact code you showed in your linked image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Solution**:
>
> The error described below has nothing to do with mathematica (as you
>   veryfied it) but with Quicktime. Mathematica used the **Quicktime**
>   **decoder** which **produced the mistake**. 
>   Quicktime extracts image 20 as beeing the same as image 19.
>
> After deinstalling Quicktime mathematica extracts the images correctly.
>
> Thanks to everybody, especially for the hint of Theo Tiger who wrote:
>   Can it be a codec issue?

See also these links:

https://github.com/SimonWoods/MathMF/

https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica

"**Mathematica's (v9 or v10) default methods uses QuickTime that produces artifact in uncompressed videos or duplicated frames.**"

Comment: (+1) Do you know which decoder *Mathematica* uses by default (when the Quicktime decoder isn't installed)? Is there an option which allows to control this behavior?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov if Quicktime isn't available Mathematica (11.1.1 on Windows) uses a Java class `System.Convert.MovieDump` (see the definition of ``System`Convert`MovieDump`MovieImport``). It looks like it's based on the out-of-date [Java Media Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework). You could probably override ``System`Convert`MovieDump`QuickTimeInstalledQ[]`` to bypass Quicktime.

Comment: @mrz, see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161/862)

Comment: @Simon Woods. Thanks dor the link. I tried to use MathMF, but I am not able to read the movie. Did you try it?

Comment: To answer both questions, yes I tried it with `Import` and with MathMF. Both worked as expected, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhu5j.png). I do not have Quicktime installed.

Comment: No, I have never had Quicktime installed on this PC.

Comment: @Simon Woods: I tested MathMF with avi files of about 100 GB size - it works excellent - see also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149269/cannot-read-in-a-movie-as-a-list-of-images .

Answer (score 0):

I got today (2017/11/10) the following email from Wolfram Technical Support:

> In Jul 2017 you reported an issue with Mathematica wherein importing
>   some uncompressed AVI files failed on Windows. We believe that the
>   issue has been resolved in the current 11.2 release of Mathematica.
>
> Thank you for your report and we look forward to a continued,
>   productive relationship with you.

And indeed the following code in version 11.2.0.0 produces the correct result:

```
Import[avifile, {"AVI", "ImageList", Range[19, 20, 1]}]
```

[image]