# Question regarding MathMF

Tags: import, video

I want to extract images from an avi file with `MathMF` from https://github.com/SimonWoods/MathMF.

(please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/importing-videos-in-mathematica/46813#46813) the answer of Simon)

A test avi file (named "20181122_test.avi") can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ek87v3mLXRHAv51jW4967vQLIO-Z-Any

Let's consider only two lines:

Line 1.    `Needs["MathMF`"];` (to load the package)

This works and the package is loaded.

Now I want to read the number of images in the file:

Line 2.   `numberImages = Length@Import["20181122_test.avi", "Frames"]`

That produces an error:

[image]

If I don't load the MathMF package BEFORE, then I get the correct result:

```
numberImages = 
 Length@Import["20181122_test.avi", "Frames"]

5
```

The funny thing is NOW I can again execute `Needs["MathMF`"]` and AFTER that I can read the number of images in the file WITHOUT error.

Can somebody reproduce the error? **What is different between Mathematica 11.3 and 11.1.1 and how can I execute with Mathematica 11.3 first line 1 and then line 2 without error?**

My OS is Windows 10 Pro 64 bit and I am working with Mathematica 11.3.0.0

> This error does not occur with Mathematica 11.1.1

Comment: @Simon Woods: do you have an idea where the problem might be?

Comment: He will not see the notification unless he has interacted with this thread before.

Comment: @Szabolcs: how can I contact him?

Comment: I would try to find contact details outside of StackExchange. If you cannot, try to comment on one of his old answers and link to here.

Comment: Judging from the error message it looks like Mathematica 11.3 is using Media Foundation (via MediaTools.dll) for the avi import (earlier versions didn't) and this is conflicting with the use of Media Foundation in my library. Most likely there is a bug in my code. I don't know C++ or COM well, so MathMF is probably not doing things quite the way they should be.

Comment: Looking at the MediaTools package it seems like it might do everything that MathMF can do anyway. If you do ``Needs["MediaTools`"]`` and then ``?MediaTools`Private`$MF*`` there appear to be functions for frame-by-frame reading and writing. Unfortunately I don't have spare time to look into it any further right now.

Comment: @Simon Woods: Thanks a lot for this two comments, which answer my question. I will look into MediaTools. Why I was using your software: It was much faster than when I extracted images with the available Mathematica routines. Im my case I have avi files of up to 100GB. Put it (if you find some time) into an answer, so to give you the +50 points.

Comment: @mrz, see my answer in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186995/9239

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the error message it looks like Mathematica 11.3 is using Media Foundation (via MediaTools.dll) for the avi import (earlier versions didn't) and this is conflicting with the use of Media Foundation in my library. Most likely there is a bug in my code. I don't know C++ or COM well, so MathMF is probably not doing things quite the way they should be.

Looking at the `MediaTools` package it seems like it might do everything that MathMF can do anyway. If you do `` Needs["MediaTools`"] `` and then `` ?MediaTools`Private`$MF* `` there appear to be functions for frame-by-frame reading and writing.

**Update**

Piotr Wendykier has provided an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186995/862) showing how to use `MediaTools` for frame-by-frame reading.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error is caused by loading `MathMF`, so I suggest modify the `MathMF` package file mannually further while executing **Needs["MathMF'"]**, in order to do this, the package main file should be modified properly.

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

then find the `MathMF.m`, open it with `Notepad` or other text editor
[image]
the content surrounded by red rectangle should be packed as a function following the package programming rules, see bellow likely

```
MFLoad[]:=Module[{},
    MathMFlib=FindLibrary["MathMF"];

    If[MathMFlib===$Failed,
     Print["No MathMF.DLL found.\nMathMF will attempt to build the library from source."];
     Module[{codefile,code},
     codefile=FileNameJoin[ReplacePart[FileNameSplit[$InputFileName],-1->"MathMF.cpp"]];
    If[!FileExistsQ[codefile],
    Print["No source file found at "<>codefile<>"\nAborting MFMath."];Abort[]];
    code=Import[codefile,"Text"];
    Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
    MathMFlib=CreateLibrary[code,"MathMF",
    "Language"->"C++",
    "CleanIntermediate"->True,
    "Libraries"->{"ole32.lib","mfreadwrite.lib","mfplat.lib","mfuuid.lib"}];
    If[!FileExistsQ[MathMFlib],
    Print["Library creation failed.\nAborting MFMath."];Abort[],
    Print["MathMF.DLL successfully created at "<>MathMFlib]]]];

    MFISR=LibraryFunctionLoad[MathMFlib,"InitSourceReader",{"UTF8String"},{Real,1}];
    MFGF=LibraryFunctionLoad[MathMFlib,"GrabFrame",{},{Integer,3}];
    MFSourceTime=LibraryFunctionLoad[MathMFlib,"SourceTime",{},Real];
    MFISW=LibraryFunctionLoad[MathMFlib,"InitSinkWriter",{"UTF8String",Integer,Integer,Integer,Real,Integer},"Void"];
    MFSF=LibraryFunctionLoad[MathMFlib,"SendFrame",{{Integer,3,"Constant"}},Integer];

Return[True];]
```

and add declaration in the usage section as

```
MFLoad::usage= "MFLoad[] load MathMF.dll and do preparation";
```

so that when **Needs["MathMF'"]** only loads packages functions but does not make initialization. Everytime you are going to use `MathMF`, you do `MFLoad[]` to call functions of `MathMF` or `MFUnload[]` to call the MMA meta-functions.

It's hard to use `TracePrint` to track the `Import` execution routing to find the error, so turn to `MathMF` author for help might be better.