# Fast export of png images from large avi file with Mathematica 11.3

Tags: performance-tuning, import, video

In version 11.1.1 I used [MathMF](https://github.com/SimonWoods/MathMF) by Simon Woods to extract png images from large avi files (up to 100GB in size). His package was ***MUCH*** faster than using something like that:

```
nImages = Length@Import["D:\\movie.avi", "Frames"];

Do[
  image = Import["D:\\movie.avi", {"Frames", i}];

  strCounter = ToString@PaddedForm[i, 5, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}];

  Export[StringJoin[outputPath, "image_", strCounter, ".png"], image, 
   "png"], {i, 1, nImages}
];
```

Already only reading the number of images of a large avi file of 6GB (containing 640*480 pixel images) takes a long time (45s). If somebody does not belive it, the file is available here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/1g2kffBySogQgtsS9).

The reading of a *single image* at a certain position `i=1` takes also about 45 sec.

Why is this so slow? (I have 32 GB of RAM, processsor: i7-4940MX 3.1 GHz)

See this:

```
image = Import["D:\\movie.avi", {"Frames", 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{44.1149, Null}
```

FOR SMALL AVI FILES THIS PROBLEM IS "INVISIBLE"!

For comparison I took VirtualDub (for Windows) and opened the 6GB avi file. In less than a second it shows the first image and the total number of files (20159).

In versions 11.3 `MathMF` does not work any more (see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186349/question-regarding-mathmf) and the comment of Simon).

Simon mentioned the following:

> Looking at the MediaTools package it seems like it might do everything
>   that MathMF can do anyway. If you do `` Needs["MediaTools`"] `` and then
>   `` ?MediaTools`Private`$MF* `` there appear to be functions for
>   frame-by-frame reading and writing.

If I execute `` ?MediaTools`Private`$MF* `` I get a list of fuctions.
[image]

**How can I substitute with these functions my upper code to increase the performance?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In version 11.3 for Windows you can do the following:

```
In[1]:= file = URLSave["http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/
Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.avi", "c:\\tmp\\sample.avi"];

In[2]:= Needs["MediaTools`"]

In[3]:= MediaTools`Private`$MFInitReader[file]

Out[3]= True

In[4]:= AbsoluteTiming[i = MediaTools`Private`$MFReadNextFrame[];]

Out[4]= {0.0497098, Null}

In[5]:= MediaTools`Private`$MFFinalizeReader[]

Out[5]= True

In[6]:= ImageDimensions[i]

Out[6]= {1920, 1080}
```

Comment: I just now test the extaction with your code and it is very fast. In my upper code example I only modified the reading by: `image = MediaToolsPrivate$MFReadNextFrame[];`. With that about 10 images per second are extracted and saved. The only thing which I do not understand: when I want to know the contained total number of images in the avi I used: `n = MediaToolsPrivate$MFReadVideoFrameCount[file];`. The first time for my 6GB avi file it takes about 40sec (result: `n = 20159`). If I execute the same line a second time it is done in fraction of a second. Do you know why this is so?

Comment: When I replace `Export[StringJoin[outputPath, "image_", strCounter, ".png"], image, 
   "png"]` by `Image`ImportExportDump`ImageWritePNG[
  StringJoin[outputPath, "image_", strCounter, ".png"], image];` in average 16 images per second are saved.

Comment: @mrz: `MediaToolsPrivate$MFReadVideoFrameCount[file];` has to decode all frames when it is evaluated for the first time. The result is cached. Video file formats store only an approximate duration (= approximate number of frames) in the header.

Comment: I understand. Without the help of Simon Woods and you, I would have never been able to solve my problem. If I search in the Mathematica help I do not find any documentation about the existence of the package `MediaTools`. Is there a possibility to list all of these „hidden“ functions?

Comment: We don't document internal paclets, but I will pass this idea.

Comment: That would be a great help for all users. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187708/memory-consumption-problem-when-reading-png-images-with-imageimportexportdumpi

Comment: The solution above does not work in Mathematica 12. Please see my question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204831/problem-with-mediatools-in-mathematica-12